# Large number of strings in php

Tags: php, arrays, list

```
<?php 
$list = array( 
    "^12\.34\.", 
    "^12\.35\.", 
);
```

The problem here is my strings, "^12.34." and so on, have to be dealt with in regex. Is there a way for php to parse large numbers of strings without having to resort to regex? Say you have so many strings and they change so often you'd prefer not to have to turning them into regex because that would mean creating a script just for that process. Is it possible? Perhaps a nice little include of another page that includes the strings, but that doesn't have to be in regex?

Comment: Just use regex, I'm not sure what the big deal is.

Comment: Why do you believe that regex is required in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You could play with trim and floatval within PHP to build a solution, but I am not sure it would be any faster.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

However, I would use regex here as it is cleaner and easier to maintain. See the choosen answer here for a good solution: [regex replace for decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142496/regex-replace-for-decimals)